# NSwag cannot handle nullable types in Dto

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nswag

In my ASP.Net Core project I use NSwag to generate clients. And everything works fine. The only problem I have is, that my nullable types are ignored in the response when they are null.

I have the following classes:

```
class ClassA {
    public int Test { get; set; }  
}

class ClassB {
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public ClassA? SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate the client, both properties will be created with the following Attribute:

> [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("someProperty", Required =
> Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling =
> Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]

I tried the following things that do not work:

- Set the NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include in my class, but it gets overridden
- Implement a partial class next to the generated one and fix the NullValueHandling, as described here (https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1129), but it still gets ignored
- Trying multiple settings that I can set in the "openApiToCSharpClient" Json Object

EDIT: ClassA should be nullable too

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct option to use this feature with NSwag. However, it is possible to customize the NSwag configuration and add this setting manually.

This example will exclude properties that are null from the JSON output using the IgnoreNullValues ​​property.

```
 var document = await OpenApiDocument.FromUrlAsync("https://example.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json");


var jsonSerializerSettings = document.ToJsonSerializerSettings();


jsonSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;


document.SerializerSettings = jsonSerializerSettings;


var codeGeneratorSettings = new CSharpClientGeneratorSettings
{
    ClassName = "MyApiClient",
    Namespace = "MyNamespace",
};
var clientCode = new CSharpClientGenerator(document, codeGeneratorSettings)
    .GenerateFile();
```

Comment: I have no idea where I should include this, because my client generation code is in a .targets file.

Answer (score 0):

modify the property to :

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("someProperty", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.AllowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include)]
```

Now the result:

[image]

Comment: This doesnt work, because the NSwag client generator resets the Attribute and sets its own.

Comment: Hi,@Febertson it does work on myside,could you share a minimal example that could reproduce your issue?

Comment: I think not, because thats company code, and making it minimal would cost me too much time.
Have you used NSwag cSharpGenerator to generate the HttpClient that returns the response? 
If I simply call my controller, your solution works, but with the generated client I have problems.